# Getting Sprite to fade back in after fade out? Entitiy Modifier

Tags: entity, andengine, sprite, fadein, fadeout

Hi im trying to get a sprite to fade in and scale up after fading out and scaling down. For this i used an Entitiy modifier listener but its not working? Heres my code:

```
public class GameScene {

Scene gameScene;
Engine engine;
Activity activity;

BitmapTextureAtlas mTextureAtlas;
ITextureRegion X;
ITextureRegion O;
ITextureRegion XO;

FadeInModifier fadeIn = new FadeInModifier(2);
FadeOutModifier fadeOut = new FadeOutModifier(2);
ScaleModifier scaleDown = new ScaleModifier(3, 1, 0);
ScaleModifier scaleUp = new ScaleModifier(2, 0, 1);

Sprite XOsprite;
Random rand = new Random();
boolean XYset = false;

public GameScene(Engine eng, Activity act) {
    engine = eng;
    activity = act;
}

public Scene getScene() {

    gameScene = new Scene();
    gameScene.setBackground(new Background(0, 256, 59));
    int x = 0, y = 0;

    if (rand.nextInt(2) == 0) {
        XO = X;
    } else {
        XO = O;
    }

    if (!XYset) {
        x = rand.nextInt(MainActivity.CAM_WIDTH);
        y = rand.nextInt(MainActivity.CAM_HEIGHT);
        XYset = true;
    }



    XOsprite = new Sprite(x, y, XO, engine.getVertexBufferObjectManager()) {
        @Override
        public boolean onAreaTouched(final TouchEvent te, final float xVal,
                final float yVal) {
            XOsprite.registerEntityModifier(fadeOut);
            XOsprite.registerEntityModifier(scaleDown);
            return true;

        }
    };
    IEntityModifierListener fadeOutListener = new IEntityModifierListener() {

        @Override
        public void onModifierStarted(IModifier<IEntity> pModifier,
                IEntity pItem) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onModifierFinished(IModifier<IEntity> pModifier,
                IEntity pItem) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            XOsprite.clearEntityModifiers();
            XOsprite.setPosition(rand.nextInt(MainActivity.CAM_WIDTH), rand.nextInt(MainActivity.CAM_HEIGHT));
            XOsprite.registerEntityModifier(fadeIn);
            XOsprite.registerEntityModifier(scaleUp);
        }
    };
    fadeOut.addModifierListener(fadeOutListener);
    XOsprite.registerEntityModifier(scaleUp);
    XOsprite.registerEntityModifier(fadeIn);

    gameScene.attachChild(XOsprite);
    gameScene.registerTouchArea(XOsprite);

    return gameScene;
}
```

The sprite just fades out and nothing happens. I also want the sprite to change to a random position on the screen when it fades back in. Help?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do  fade in and  scale in  parallel then you can use use parallelEntityModifier.

Similarly for  fade out and  scale out  parallel then you can use use parallelEntityModifier.

To run these two in sequence use  SequenceEntityModifier.
Try this it will work.